# How can I tweak my Camera2 API settings to match the quality of the stock camera app?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

For my task, I need the highest quality (sharpness specifically) still image capture possible.

However, I am new to the Camera2API and its numerous settings I can adjust. These are the ones I curerently have set:

```
fullResRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
fullResRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_EDOF);
fullResRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, (byte)100);
fullResRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
fullResRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_ABERRATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_ABERRATION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
fullResRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
fullResRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE, CaptureRequest.EDGE_MODE_HIGH_QUALITY);
```

My Reader:

```
fullQualityReader = ImageReader.newInstance(4608, 2592, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);
```

But I am not able to reach the quality of the stock OnePlus 5T camera. Here is a comparison:
left is from my app, right is from the stock app.

[Side-by-side image comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVqii.jpg)

Would appreciate any help in getting to the quality of the stock app or better. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell looking at so dramatically zoomed out pictures, but maybe your problem is not the 'highest quality' and not going for maximum resolution. I see some artifacts on the right-side image that don't show on your photo, but the contrast on the right seems better. Were these pictures taken in very low light conditions?

Comment: The resolutions are mostly the same, see the bottom left corner of both pics, please. I think there are some settings (in Camera2) that OnePlus has applied, which I am not yet aware of. The contrast is a good point, will investigate. These pictures were taken under normal office lighting conditions, definitely not something that would be considered low-light.

Comment: If you are concerned with the barcode, try much lower resolution. If you want to see that piece above, there is not enough detail in the picture you posted. Please zoom into it in your irfanview.

Comment: I should have mentioned, the aim is to scan from as far as possible. I tried various resolutions, and it looks like distance (from which scanning is possible) is directly proportional to the resolution, makes sense right? I am just hoping, by sharpening(?) the image like the stock app, I can increase the scanning distance a bit more.

Comment: you can try to zoom in instead of going for very high resolution

Comment: Will do, thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you ever come up with a good solution to make the quality good?

Comment: Nothing concrete but you just have to go through all the available settings for CaptureRequest and set the ones you think will help.